# Is there a reason why I am getting this unexpected result for >> operator?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have a long which is made with this code:

```
long binary = 0b1L<< 63;
```

This gives the expected result, a one at the 63rd index:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But when I take this long, and apply the >> operator to it, it gives me an unexpected result.
For example, when I call this code snippet on the above binary:

```
long newBinary = binary >>8;
```

It shifts right the right amount, but it fills the leading zeros with ones:

```
1111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Is there a specific reason why this is happening?

Comment: `>>` is not a logical shift. It does an _arithmetic shift_. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Wow. I cant believe I didnt know this. Should i be using >>> instead?

Comment: Yes, `>>>` is for logical shifts.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is the signed right shift operator, which fills the leftmost position with the sign bit (leftmost bit of the original number) each time. On the other hand, the unsigned right shift operator, `>>>`, always fills with `0`.

**Steps:**

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Shift right 8 positions:

```
000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Fill shifted bits on the left with original sign bit (1):

```
111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

See also: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)